# why do we increment the ostream iterator here

Tags: c++, iterator

I am currently reading about the ostream iterator (iterator adaptor) and the author gives the following example:

```
/* Declare an ostream_iterator that writes ints to cout. */
ostream_iterator<int> myItr(cout, " ");
/* Write values to the iterator. These values will be printed to cout. */
*myItr = 137; // Prints 137 to cout
++myItr;
*myItr = 42; // Prints 42 to cout
++myItr
```

I am curious as to why the example does ++myItr after assigning value into it ?

Comment: Are you asking this because you happen to know, in this special case, that the increment operation is actually a no-op?  Or are you unfamiliar with iterators in general, and this kind of syntax completely foreign to you? If the latter, dasblinkenlight has the answer. If the former, then it's for the sake of consistency with other iterator types, where the operation isn't a no-op.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterators are modeled after pointers; this includes output iterators. When you copy data to a region pointed to by a pointer, you dereference the pointer, make an assignment, and then increment the pointer. You do the same to iterators, including these of the output variety <sup>*</sup>.

It is customary to combine the increment with the assignment, like this:

```
*myItr++ = 137; // Prints 137 to cout
*myItr++ = 42; // Prints 42 to cout
```

When an iterator expects to be assigned and incremented, you can mix and match iterators and algorithms expecting them. For example, you can perform printing of a container by calling `std::copy` - the same algorithm that you can use to copy one container into another, copy a container into an array, or populate a container from an array.

---

<sup>*</sup> It is worth to note that both overloads of `++` do nothing for `ostream_iterator`. They are included to satisfy the requirements of `OutputIterator`. See [this link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator/operator_arith) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the answer could you explain why the need to increment the pointer is a necessity ? What happens if you dont ?

Comment: @MistyD When you know for sure that the iterator is of the output kind, increment is not necessary, because it's a no-op. It is necessary only when you write an algorithm that expects any kind of iterator.

Comment: There may be instances of output iterators for which the increment is significant, raw pointers are the obvious example, although in many cases the increment operation does nothing just as it does for `ostream_iterator`.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically for the ostream_iterator class, the operator++() operator is not required to have any effect, since streams advance automatically on insertion in C++. 
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/ostream_iterator/operator++/